# Jquery .click method failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like I must be missing something obvious but I can't see it for the life of me.
When I run the following:

```
$wizContent.append(
    $("<content>").css({
        position:"relative",
        height:"428px"
    }).append(
        $("<div>").addClass("addItem").append(
            $("<div>")
            .click(function(){
                alert("!");                 
                addAttToSec({name:'new Attr'});
            })
            .addClass("plus").html("+")
        )
    ).append(
        $("<div>").addClass("secAtts").append(parseSecAttributes(secData))
    )
);
```

And click on the button it creates, it does nothing, no JavaScript errors, just nothing. The Object is appending correctly and it is certainly the correct object I'm clicking on. Any Ideas?

Comment: remove the '<' & '>' from the selectrors: $('content')

Comment: @ahmed That's probably not the issue; it seems that the OP wishes to create `<content>` and `<div>` elements (to append to `$wizContent`), not select all `<content>` and `<div>` elements.

Comment: What if you assign the `div` you're trying to append to a variable, set the click event to that variable and then append it. Or append the variable and set the click event after.

Comment: @apsillers Correct, I am creating a <contant> section

Comment: @Jeff Can you create a simple runnable example, either here as a Stack Snippet or JSFiddle (or JSBin, etc.)?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1fj5rtjs/

Comment: that fiddle works for me? intended behaviour is that you click on the plus and you get an alert, right? what browser are you working in

Comment: This may be a problem with styling, not scripting. I suspect you are likely covering up your clickable region with another (invisible) element.

Comment: @apsillers actually very difficult to fiddle as it is very database dependent. I am using Chrome. I F12 selected the element, it seems to be on top.

Comment: Hmm it may be due to the library: jquery steps, let me explore this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems that a library I was using, [steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/), was striping my events for some reason.
Applying the binds after the steps call seems to make it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code in jsfiddle and it worked:

```
var $wizContent = $('#wiz-content');

$wizContent.append(
    $("<content>").css({
        position:"relative",
        height:"428px"
    }).append(
        $("<div>").addClass("addItem").append(
            $("<div>")
            .click(function(){
                alert("!");                 
                //addAttToSec({name:'new Attr'});
            })
            .addClass("plus").html("+")
        )
    ).append(
        $("<div>").addClass("secAtts")
    )
);
```

Here is the fiddle thats working:
https://jsfiddle.net/w44n8fk1/

Comment: .click can be used to send a click event, but only if no parameter is sent with it.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I got a bit confused.

Comment: I have editied my answer, after trying out the code in jsFiddle